# Angular ui.router any event before insert view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to insert css/js before view content is assigned.
`$stateChangeStart`, `$stateChangeSuccess`, `$viewContentLoaded` aren't figuring out my problem.
I want to write code like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$beforeInsertHtml', function(event, state) {
    if (state.files) {
        updateFiles(state.files); // my loader
    }
});
```

Any solutions?
Looks like I need to change source code and add additional event.

Answer (score 1):

try with $viewContentLoading, this event is broadcasted by $view low-level service